# FFmpeg: fade in and fade out doesn't work with filter_complex

Tags: ffmpeg, mobile-ffmpeg

I have several audio files in Mac application that I need to merge so that the finished file starts with a fade in, then crossfade between audio files, and ends by fade out.

I have the following query and it works only partially. Crossfade works perfectly, but fade in and fade out does not work at all.
`-y -i '/Users/george.lucas/Desktop/Task5/Task5/Task5/Sounds/billie_eilish_happier_than_ever.mp3' -i '/Users/george.lucas/Desktop/Task5/Task5/Task5/Sounds/Linkin_Park_California.mp3' -i '/Users/george.lucas/Desktop/Task5/Task5/Task5/Sounds/Rammstein â Du riechst so gut.mp3' -filter_complex "\[0\] atrim=60.780234547806856:152.71856767246777, afade=enable='between(t, 0, 60.0)':t=in:st=0:d=60.0 \[outdf0\]; \[1\] atrim=37.65177079420725:153.98897875714704  \[trm1\];\[outdf0\]\[trm1\] acrossfade=d=60.0:c1=exp:c2=exp \[outdf1\]; \[2\] atrim=106.79850757480907:196.73409290096407  \[trm2\];\[outdf1\]\[trm2\] acrossfade=d=60.0:c1=exp:c2=exp \[outdf2\]; \[outdf2\] afade=enable='between(t,29.935585326155007, 60.0)':t=out:st=29.935585326155007:d=60.0 \[outtotal\] " -map \[outtotal\] '/Users/george.lucas/Library/Containers/com.someinitials/Data/Library/Application Support/mergedfile.m4a'`

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you came to the conclusion that "it does not work"?

Comment: Thanks for attention. Just merged file have not fade in the beginning, and fade out in the its end. But crossfade between tracks that make up a full track works fine

Comment: What happens if you remove `enable` options?

Comment: Then I get audio file with total duration equal sum of part files, BUT after first audio file ends there's total silence